# Prove that $\{ f \in X : f(0) = 0 \}$ is closed

Tags: functional-analysis

> Denote $X$ to be the set of all Holder continuous functions with constant $C$ and order $\alpha$. So $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{\alpha}$. Prove that $A = \{ f \in X : f(0) = 0 \}$ is closed in $C[0,1]$.

So I start with a convergent sequence $ f_n$ in $A$ and show that its limit $f \in C[0,1]$ is in $W$. I think I only have to show that $f$ is Holder continuous and $f(0) = 0$? I think for $f(0) \neq 0$, we have $y = f(0) \neq 0$, then convergence of $f_n$ means for $y/2$, we have (assume WLOG, $y > 0$)

$$\| f _n(x) - f(x) \|_\infty < y/2 $$

$$\| f_n(0) - f(0) \| < y/2$$

$$\| f(0 ) \| < y/2$$

a contradiction? How do I show $f$ is Holder continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f$ , then:

$|f(0)| = |f(0) - f_n(0) + f_n(0)| \leq ||f(x) - f_n(x)||_{\infty} + |f_n(0)| = 0$

When $n \rightarrow \infty$. So $f(0) = 0$. Using a similar argument you can see it is Hölder.

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f(x) - f(y) - f_n(x) + f_n(x) - f_n(y) + f_n(y)|$$ $$\leq ||f(x) - f_n(x)||_{\infty} + ||f(y) - f_n(y)||_{\infty} + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \leq C|x-y|^{\alpha}$$

Comment: um I already know how to show $f(0) =0$, it's the Holder I am asking in the question.

Comment: If you are suggesting $|f(x) - f(y) + f_n - f_n|$, that is not going to work.

Comment: @jip There it is.

Comment: Your edit doesn't work either, how do you justify $\| f(x) - f_n(x) \|_\infty < C|x-y|^{\alpha}$ anyways?

Comment: Oh never mind, we didn't cared about that. It just goes to $0$.

Comment: $f_n \rightarrow f$.. so the distance goes to $0$.

Comment: I am right that I only need to show those properties right?

Comment: @jip Yes, you need to show $f$ has the property of your set, that is Hölder and $0$ at $0$.